# Feedforward equalizer MMSE vs ZF: I get ZF performs better than MMSE, why is that?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, digital-communications, equalization, equalizer

So I am doing some experiments on comparing MMSE and ZF performance. Here is the description of my problem setup:

Consider a pulse response $p_{tilde}$ which is equal to:

[7.41283693728174e-06
-6.84231291007695e-05
-0.0443418886383774
-0.0151503353629903
-0.0272769624198551
-0.0177892552560615
-0.0203350692581077
-0.0163873767272264
-0.0164306282845029
-0.0142362825364328
-0.0136655824141384
-0.0121940540773202
-0.0114619811302311
-0.0104124216153988
-0.00964899540994174
-0.00899196802973862
-0.00818566902044469
-0.00762730911499311
-0.00699141833441100
-0.00648613497013486
-0.00591440709340248
-0.00553607986409091
-0.00505027582877288
-0.00474052280850206
-0.00430261543533403
-0.00402597225213157
-0.00364873023512323
-0.00342623983233682
-0.00309870405925617
-0.00287855285961599
-0.00259826586794989
-0.00242555114477522
-0.00216311155170253
-0.00201954752590112
-0.00187659490896144
-0.00169995749278872
-0.00160002957958732
-0.00143570523645728
-0.00137503899976676
-0.00125830844814117
-0.00119472748925794
-0.00110403717898079
-0.00103406206999471
-0.000958275964792411
-0.000911849041772657
-0.000845030004218205
-0.000816232809699085
-0.000667539573097499
-0.000648754798002034
-0.000553122573229280
-0.000521309202162978
-0.000365972657867558
-0.000427904780904760
-0.000303965793819752
-0.000299468601099196
-0.000225217170299876
-0.000159927160163347
-4.27943799247876e-05
5.77535188454308e-06
-1.60324544347288e-05
7.58340989099088e-05
4.90191180358249e-05
5.55787742344576e-05]

After using MMSE algorithm, which is defined as (https://github.com/igorauad/digital_communication_ee379/blob/master/chap3/fir_mmse_le_pam_example.mlx):

```
nu = length(p_tilde) - 1;
N = 1; % Number of dimensions per symbol
Nf = 30; % number of FFE taps
L = 1; % oversampling ratio
Ex = 1;
Ex_bar = Ex / N;

% First split p into blocks (columns) of L samples each
% Number of blocks:
n_blocks = 1 + ceil((length(p_tilde)-1)/L);
% Last block may require zero-padding
if (mod(length(p_tilde)-1,L) ~= 0)
    n_missing_samples = L - mod(length(p_tilde)-1,L);
else
    n_missing_samples = 0;
end
% Zero-pad and split:
p_0 = [p_tilde(1); zeros(L-1,1)];
p_split = [p_0 flipud(reshape([p_tilde(2:end) ...
            zeros(1,n_missing_samples)], L, n_blocks-1))]
% Note: flipud is used to distribute the p_tilde samples as a CW
% commutator over the L branches of the polyphase decomposition

% Generate a Toeplitz matrix

nRows = Nf * L;
nCol = Nf + nu;
% Preallocate
P = zeros(nRows, nCol);

nZerosRight = nCol - (nu + 1);
nZerosLeft = 0;

nBlocks = Nf;

for iBlock = 1:nBlocks
    P((iBlock-1)*L + 1 : (iBlock*L),:) = [zeros(L, nZerosLeft) p_split zeros(L, nZerosRight)];
    nZerosLeft = nZerosLeft + 1;
    nZerosRight = nZerosRight - 1;
end

[a,b]= max(abs(sampled_channel_coefficients_afe));
delta = b-1;  % see page 21 at https://people.engr.tamu.edu/spalermo/ecen689/lecture7_ee689_eq_intro_txeq.pdf; here I assume no FFE pre-cursor

% Cross-correlation
R_Yx = Ex_bar * P * [zeros(delta,1); 1; zeros(Nf + nu - delta - 1, 1)]

% Auto-correlation
SNR_dB = 32.126534578279106;
SNR = 10^(SNR_dB/10); % Note this is not SNRmfb ("one-shot" bound), but simply the receiver biased SNR
noise_en_per_dim = Ex_bar/SNR 
R_YY_mmse = (Ex_bar * P * P') + (L * noise_en_per_dim *eye(Nf*L))
R_YY_zf = (Ex_bar * P * P')

% MMSE
w_mmse = (inv(R_YY_mmse)*R_Yx)'
w_zf = (inv(R_YY_zf)*R_Yx)'
```

If you run the above code, you will get the following tap weights:

$w_{mmse}$ = [-16.0334968779402
4.81345350767911
6.45455599790458
1.05531267863522
0.862544811465639
0.154226345074783
0.155009947755956
0.00415771541535660
0.0469282011013412
-0.00373585377344961
0.0126325827750029
0.00933571396627974
-0.00280141664202185
0.0401862503056695
-0.0156342273933104
0.00299196074830827
7.48619764623058e-05
0.00295098323035444
-0.0120788898062787
0.0136305155251233
-0.00262402928039840
0.0114544066067792
-0.00947152098371525
0.00218325999598388
-0.00962498002977390
0.00565329024769428
-0.00760605356156193
-0.00330735044519261
-0.00936301791652029
0.00463602328709300]

$w_{zf}$ = [-22.5610583952446
7.69159287211292
11.2502110473252
0.475800804762431
0.177960155261523
-0.0564236911727865
0.0770702791028816
-0.0456116693343436
0.0481983891750188
-0.0136058797432089
0.00953080508217355
0.0111016906882175
-0.0107606798793674
0.0785469849940052
-0.0363898394254151
-0.00916857774920463
0.00864999071589379
0.00320710119648796
-0.0254101797448969
0.0258281970465915
-0.000640995082141195
0.0179348156324128
-0.0180090776779173
0.000496679609183903
-0.0144388420218252
0.0133258761460034
-0.0101177143789741
-0.00842776943416558
-0.0144975418511249
0.0119841389349415]

Now, we run the time domain analysis:

```
M = 4; % PAM4
N = 1e7; % number of symbols
sampled_channel_coefficients_afe = p_tilde;
tap_weights_ffe_zf = w_zf;
tap_weights_ffe_mmse = w_mmse;

% generate PAM4 data
data = randi([0, M-1], N, 1);
modData = real(pammod(data,M,0,'gray'));
% convolve with sampled_channel_coefficients_afe
signal_in = conv(modData, sampled_channel_coefficients_afe);
Ex = mean((abs(signal_in.^2)));
% SNR
SNR = 32.126534578279106; % dB
% AWGN channel
signal_in_awgn = awgn(signal_in, SNR, 'measured');   %- input signal to equalize

% no noise:
eyediagram(signal_in(N-3000:N-1000),3);            
% no eq but with noise:
eyediagram(signal_in_awgn(N-3000:N-1000),3);            
% equalized using ZF:
signal_eq_zf = conv(signal_in_awgn, tap_weights_ffe_zf, 'same');
tap_weights_ffe_zf = tap_weights_ffe_zf/max(abs(signal_eq_zf));
signal_eq_zf = conv(signal_in_awgn, tap_weights_ffe_zf, 'same');
eyediagram(signal_eq_zf(N-3000:N-1000),3);            
% equalized using MMSE: 
signal_eq_mmse = conv(signal_in_awgn, tap_weights_ffe_mmse, 'same');
tap_weights_ffe_mmse = tap_weights_ffe_mmse/max(abs(signal_eq_mmse));
signal_eq_mmse = conv(signal_in_awgn, tap_weights_ffe_mmse, 'same');
eyediagram(signal_eq_mmse(N-3000:N-1000),3);           
% equalized using LMS: 
eq = comm.LinearEqualizer('NumTaps', 30, 'Constellation', [-3, -1, 1, 3], 'InputDelay', 1);
[signal_eq_lms, error, tap_weights_ffe_lms] = eq(signal_in_awgn, modData);
eyediagram(signal_eq_lms(N-3000:N-1000),3);
```

And this is the eye of ZF equalized signal:

[image]

And this is the eye of MMSE equalized signal:

[image]

And finally this is the eye of LMS equalized signal:

[image]

As you can see, ZF is clearly better MMSE even the signal is in AWGN channel with a SNR = 32.126534578279106 dB

**So my question is, why this is the case?**
**This is confusing me for a while so any input and help will be extremely helpful!**

Comment: You assumed that the signal dimension is 1. On the other hand, the noise is complex, meaning, it is two dimensional. I recommend you to check your noise definition. MMSE is always better than ZF, in the presence of perfect noise variance.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Seems there is something wrong with my MMSE equation, where I have fixed in my code at GitHub already... https://github.com/ChrisZonghaoLi/mmse_dfe